# javascript Invalid regular expression with token '\'

Tags: javascript, regex, grunt-contrib-connect, connect-modrewrite

i created the following regex for finding a url matching a word in the complete path and that does't contain the point character.

```
(\path\?*)([^.]*)$
```

It works on https://www.regex101.com/#javascript, but on grunt in the connect task when i define this connect task:

```
middleware: function(connect, options) {
 var middlewares = [];

 middlewares.push(modRewrite(["(\path\?*)([^.]*)$ /home.html [L]"])); 
    options.base.forEach(function(base) {
      middlewares.push(connect.static(base));
    });
    return middlewares;
  }
```

i got this error: `Invalid regular expression: /(home?*)([^.]*)$/: Nothing to repeat` and the IDE warn me in the two slash (\path\ ) between the 'path ' word.

Why i can use those slashes?
What can i use to replace those slashes?
Thanks very much

Comment: `"(\\path\\?*)([^.]*)$ /home.html [L]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\` is a special character in javascript so you need to escape it, if you intend to use it. You can escape it by adding another `\`. ex: `\\`

Answer (score 0):

*Backslash belongs to "Javascript special characters"*

Because you use backslashes inside a double quoted string, you have to write each one twice to tell the parser that you actually want to ouput a backslah.
This is mandatory inside double quoted and single quoted strings.

You might browse the documentation .. for instance [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals)

Then search for "JavaScript special characters"